# Can I override AcitveRecord::Base#to_json on a model instance?

Tags: ruby, mixins

In Rails 2.3 I have a Rails engine which has its own namespaced controllers, but which will use the main app's models.

However, I want to override the default behavior of ActiveRecord::Base#to_json method *but only when the model is being used from the Engine*.

So in an Engine controller is it reasonable to do something like...

```
category.questions.each do |qst|
  # override ActiveRecord::Base#to_json somehow on the qst instance 
end
```

...if it is reasonable conceptually, how would I actually go about such a thing?

If it's not reasonable, what is the best way to override ActiveRecord::Base#to_json for the Engine only, and not the main app?

Thanks,

Paul

Comment: Why do you need to override `to_json` if it's only being used in the engine.  Can't you use a different method name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using `instance_eval`:

```
category.questions.each do |qst|
  qst.instance_eval do
    # do something here
  end
end
```

However, I'm not sure if this is actually an appropriate strategy for what you want to do. A simpler approach would be to make a differently named method and use that in place of `to_json` in your engine.